# How do I send the result of a function to a third one without a return?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to call a Cloudant map function in a NodeJS service for the purposes of a unit test.

I've created my own emit function but I still can't get the view to return what I need.

```
const data = {
    "_id": "68e3d2807c0faa169d504068db99e03f",
    "_rev": "2-c3b3249a2eb090e87dc4c053712691c3",
    "type": "user",
    "name": "Whatever",
    "email": "Whatever@google.com",
    "cn": "5517605X",
    "phone": null,
    "deleted": true
}

const emit = function (arg1, arg2) {
    return { key: arg1, value: arg2 };
};

var map = function (doc) {
    if (doc.type && doc.type === 'user') {
        emit([doc.cn, doc.deleted], doc);
    }
};

const result = map(data);
console.log(result);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3eem4k10/) to what I'm trying to do. I know I can fix it by just adding a return in front of the emit function but I'm not able to edit the map function as I'm getting the view straight from Cloudant.

Is there a way I can still make this work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) *"JSFiddle to what I'm trying to do"* A [mcve] needs to be **here**, on-site. I've answered based on the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I'm not able to edit the map function

Then you can't change the `map` function's return. Calling it will always result in `undefined`. There's no way around that other than changing `map` (or using something else).

---

In the specific case you've shown, `emit` could close over `result` and set it directly if you moved the `result` declaration up above `emit` and made it a `let`:

```
let result;
const emit = function (arg1, arg2) {
    result = { key: arg1, value: arg2 };
    return result;
};

var map = function (doc) {
    if (doc.type && doc.type === 'user') {
        emit([doc.cn, doc.deleted], doc);
    }
};

map(data);
console.log(result);
```

...but that's very specific to that code, and even if you don't go for a full-on functional programming approach, it's not great to have functions with side-effects like that. But sometimes needs must.